# Add additional site page library to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

It seems like it should be possible. But I can't see how to do it.

Is it possible to add an additional site page library in a SharePoint site.

I can add document libraries just fine but it doesn't appear as I can create a page library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Site Pages` library is a special library type in modern sites.  It cannot be duplicated at this time.  The most common reason for wanting another `Site Pages` library is usually for permission control en masse rather than on each individual page.  The current recommended way to handle this is to use folders in the library instead.

By default, folders are disabled for the `Site Pages` library, but it can be enabled from the library's settings page under the `Advanced Settings` section.

Comment: Thanks, that is one of the reasons.  The other is I have a use case where I would be creating a good amount of pages (as meeting agendas/minutes) just looking for a way to organize.  Also using a custom.content type which has some additional columns that the normal site pages don't need. And it was confusing for some people thinking they weren't providing the information needed.

Answer (score 1):

No, we cannot add another page library in SharePoint Online. This is by design. Creating a folder is the best alternative. By the way, you can post feedback here: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/06735c62-321c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472, share your feedback and help us make improvements.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of content management it doesn't make sense to throw all news items into the same library as permanent pages. I would think most organizations would want a separate site pages library for news.